# is there a way to change the default circular play button on iOS devices, iPhone/ipad to a custom image

Tags: ios, iphone, html, ipad, video

I have some html5 videos in my site and on iOS mobile devices it shows the default player controls which are fine but on load you have the standard circular play button before you play the video which ideally I'd like to change to a custom play triangle to match the overall aesthetic of the site.

Is there a snippet of code that I could use to change this?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No , You cant change anything which present on default audio player . Actually previously I have tried that. Also iPhone not supports `inline video play` . You have to play video on in the default player itself .

Comment: With iOS 10 you can now use inline video!